# Avoid rendrawing chart, D3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am drawing a scatter chart with `NVD3` library in `React` when a component is first mounted. I hide and show the component depending on the buttons clicked. Each time the component appears, it is mounted, so it is re-drawn but I want to avoid the redrawing, doing some kind of caching of the chart since it takes quite a bit of time to draw the chart with many datapoints. I am calling `createScatterChart` in `componentDidMount`:

```
createScatterChart() {
  const node = this.node
  nv.utils.symbolMap.set('thin-x', function(size) {
    size = Math.sqrt(size);
    return 'M' + (-size/2) + ',' + (-size/2) +
            'l' + size + ',' + size +
            'm0,' + -(size) +
            'l' + (-size) + ',' + size;
  });
// create the chart
  var chart;
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
        .showDistX(true)
        .showDistY(true)
        .useVoronoi(true)
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
        .duration(300)
    ;
    var data_func = () => this.props.datum;
    var data_obj = data_func();
    var that = this;
    chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
      //var html = "<div>";
      var html = "";
      d.series.forEach(function(elem){
        Object.keys(data_obj).forEach(function(key_1) {
          var outer_obj = data_obj[key_1];
          if (outer_obj["key"] === elem.key) {
              that.showBarChart(elem.key);
              html += "<p>cluster " + elem.key + "</p>";
              /*var expr = outer_obj["values"][0]["expr"];
              html += "<p>" + elem.key + "</p>";
              html += "<p>x = " + d.value + ", y = " + elem.value + "</p>";*/
          }
        });
      })
      //html += "</div>";
      return html;
    });

    chart.dispatch.on('renderEnd', function(){
        console.log('render complete');
    });

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

    d3.select(node)
        .datum(data_func)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { ('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });
    return chart;
}.bind(this));
}
```

The function ultimately returns `chart`, so could I somehow save it in a variable and then draw it much faster? Or what would you recommend for such caching of the chart?

Comment: How do you hide the chart?

Comment: I am hiding and showing the whole component that contains the chart. It is done in the container component, and depending on a variable `showInnerComponent`, I am hiding or showing it in `render()`

Comment: I had already same problem, but it was solved by changing `visible` attribute of my html element. so it may be a solution. but if the problem persists (after checking my solution) add your html code to the question to determine what exactly happens in the code

Comment: Absolutely! It solved my issue. I also used the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667773/what-is-the-react-js-way-of-handling-visibility-hidden

Comment: I'm happy to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by changing `visible` attribute of the html element instead of rendering it.

```
<div visibility={this.state.showButton ? "visible": "hidden"} ></div>
```